# Excel: find matching text against reference and paste corresponding values from reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How can I perform a check for identical text between two worksheets. Then when I find a match I would like to paste a specific range of columns corresponding to a given text. For example:

```
worksheet 1
column N has values
e
e
a
b
e
c
d


worksheet 2
col A     col B     col C     col D
a         0.1       0.1       0.1
b         0.3       0.5       0.3
c         0.3       0.1       0.4
d         0.3       0.2       0.5
e         0.5       0.6       0.9
```

This way Worksheet 2 is the reference. We want to filter Column N in Worksheet 1 against Worksheet 2 Column A. If we find a match we want to take the corresponding values from Columns B, C, D and put them into Worksheeet 1 after Column N (say Columns O, P, Q).

How could I do this with a formula or a VB macro?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You probably want to use `VLOOKUP()` (formula) for this. There are plenty of resources online as to its use.

Answer (score 0):

Name A:D in Worksheet 2 (say array) and apply `=VLOOKUP($N2,array,COLUMN()-13,FALSE)` in `O2` of Worksheet 1 (assuming the top `e` is in `N2`) and copy across and down as required.

Answer (score 0):

**U** sing Formula Vlookup you can do it as follow :

> **assuming** you have value in N column  i,e. a,b,c,d etc. in sheet1 and refrence values in range of column A to E whiles A containing
>   refrence value i.e. a,b,c,c etc. in sheet 2
>
> Enter the following code in Sheet 1 in mentinoed cell and drag it down
>   the rows in sheet 1

```
=VLOOKUP(N1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$3,2,FALSE) in O1 cell
=VLOOKUP(N1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$3,3,FALSE) in P1 Cell
=VLOOKUP(N1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$3,4,FALSE) in Q1 cell
```

note: you will need to modify the range in Vlookup as per the length of you reference data currently it will cover only first three row $A$1:$E$3 and 4 column.